# What is a trivial function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

[basic.def.odr]/3 makes a reference to the term "nontrivial function", whose definition I couldn't find in the Standard (N4140).

[basic.def.odr]/3

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression
>   ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
>   (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke
>   any nontrivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of
>   the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a
>   discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"non-trivial function" is the complement of "trivial special member function". There are definitions for what a trivial and non-trivial default/copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment operator or destructor is - traits that only appertain to special member functions, and decide whether e.g. these need to be called under certain circumstances.

The definitions for these can be found in chapter §12.

**Default constructor**, §12.1/4:

> A default constructor is *trivial* if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial default
>     constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is *non-trivial*.

**Copy/move constructors**, §12.8/12:

> A copy/move constructor for class X is *trivial* if it is not
>   user-provided, its *parameter-type-list* is equivalent to the
>   *parameter-type-list* of an implicit declaration, and if
>
> - class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - class `X` has no non-static data members of volatile-qualified type, and
> - the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected to copy/move that member is
>     trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move constructor is *non-trivial*.

**Copy/move assignment operator**, §12.8/26:

> A copy/move assignment operator for class `X` is *trivial* if it is
>   not user-provided, its *parameter-type-list* is equivalent to the
>   *parameter-type-list* of an implicit declaration, and if
>
> - class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - class `X` has no non-static data members of volatile-qualified type, and
> - the assignment operator selected to copy/move each direct base class
> - for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the assignment operator selected to copy/move that
>     member is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move assignment operator is *non-trivial*.

**Destructor**, §12.4/5:

> A destructor is *trivial* if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - the destructor is not virtual,
> - all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
> - for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class has a trivial
>     destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is *non-trivial*

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the reason for the term "trivial function" being used in [basic.def.odr]/3. Could you give an example in which a **constant** object of a class would be considered **odr-used**, when invoking a non-trivial member function, i.e., a non-trivial constructor, or a non-trivial destructor, or a non-trivial copy-move assignment operator?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this small example will help you understand nontrivial function in the context of [basic.def.odr]/3

```
struct C
{ 
    int l; 
    constexpr C(int _l) : l(_l) { } 
    constexpr C(const C&c) : q(c.l * 2) { } 
}; 
    
int main()
{ 
    constexpr C c{42}; 
    constexpr int m = c.l; 
    
    struct K
    { 
        int foo() { return c.l; } 
    }
    K l; 
    return l.foo(); 
}
```

If you look at the following line in standard

> applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.19) that does not invoke any nontrivial functions

Here `c` satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression, but applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to a invokes a
non-trivial function.

**Why does it invokes a non-trivial function?**

When an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion occurs in an unevaluated operand or a sub-expression thereof the value contained in the referenced object is not accessed. Otherwise, if the glvalue has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes a temporary of type `T` from the glvalue and the result of the conversion is a prvalue for the temporary.

So a prvalue is created using the copy constructor of class `C` and since copy constructor is user-defined, It is non-trivial and Hence c is not ODR-used here

A copy/move assignment operator for class X is trivial if it is not user-provided, its parameter-type-list is equivalent to the parameter-type-list of an implicit declaration.